# css - how to get floated divs to stack when you zoom in

Tags: css, stack, inline

In this responsive design I am trying for, I have three divs floating side-by-side, which get narrower and narrower when you zoom in on them. I would like them to keep their size and stack instead. How do I do this? I am beginning jquery, but for this would prefer to stick to css if possible.

Here is the relevant styling I have for the divs and their parent container div:

```
#container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:110%}

.floating-div {
width:27%;
min-width:27%;
height:420px;
float:left;}
```

Thanks for reading~

Comment: why do they get narrower when you zoom in?

Comment: solved it. I changed width % to px for the floating div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. I changed width % to px for the floating div.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served using CSS and breakpoints on view ports to manage the display for your HTML:

CSS Tricks shows how to set up CSS for this purpose: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

From the code above, there needs to also be a max-width declaration so that as the element is zoomed, it will push the next div down on the page.